Rotating Credentials with typeorm?
I have a typescript project that connects to an Aurora database with TypeOrm.  For security reasons, my password expires and is regenerated every 15 minutes using AWS- the new password is updated in a file my application reads from. I need typeorm to use this new password.
Thus far I've tried using typeorm's poolErrorHandler to get a new password when there is an error in the connection:
const config: ConnectionOptions = {
    type: <any>type,
    host,
    port: Number(port),
    username,
    password: getPassword(),
    database,
    logging: Boolean(logging),
    poolErrorHandler: (err: any) => {
        const retryAttempts = 10;
        let attempt = 0;
        const retryDelayMs = 1500000;
        setInterval(async () => {
            console.log("retrying connection");
        }, retryDelayMs);
        if (attempt >= retryAttempts) {
            throw new Error("Failed to connect to database");
        }
        password = getPassword();

    },
    entities,
};

However this doesn't seem to be working.  Does anyone have any suggestions as to how best to rotate credentials in a typeorm project?
thanks!
